# Infinite scroll Table using Semantic UI React (Table, Sticky, Visibility components) causing `<tr> cannot appear as a child of <div>` warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have created a table with infinite scrolling using Semantic UI React.  I am using a combination of `Sticky`, `Table`, `Visibility` components.  It appears to be behaving correctly and accomplishing what I want.

However I get the following warnings:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <thead>.
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <div>.
```

Can I safely ignore these warnings?  Everything seems to be working fine, I am just afraid of bigger issues down the road.

I am trying to find a better way of implementing infinite scroll without having the warnings listed above.  Here is the current implementation:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Sticky, Table, Visibility } from 'semantic-ui-react'


class InfiniteScrollTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {}
  }

  handleContextRef = contextRef => this.setState({ contextRef })

  render() {
    const { contextRef } = this.state
    const { children, headerRow, ...rest } = this.props

    return (
      <div ref={this.handleContextRef}>
        <Table {...rest}>

          <Table.Header>
            <Sticky context={contextRef}>{headerRow}</Sticky>
          </Table.Header>

          <Visibility
            as="tbody"
            continuous={false}
            once={false}
            onBottomVisible={() => console.log('This will call API')}
          >
            {children}
          </Visibility>

        </Table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


InfiniteScrollTable.propTypes = {
  headerRow: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.element).isRequired,
}

InfiniteScrollTable.defaultProps = {}

export default InfiniteScrollTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that react is warning you that you are nesting your variables incorrectly. While it works fine on the browser you are testing, it could break on other browsers that implement the DOM slightly differently.

I would suggest you correct this issue by moving the `Sticky` to the top of the table and passing `<Visibility as={Table.Body}...` or `<Visibility as="tbody"...`. Not sure if these would work, but that is how I would fix it if I were to use a similar framework.

Comment: consider maybe have the `Visibility` just wrap the whole table, and then have the header as a separate div above it?

Comment: or even have the `Visibility` be `as="tbody"` ?

Comment: This corrected it for the table body (I updated the question).  However, the header is a little complicated because if I make the header cells contain the `Sticky`, then the errors go away, but I lose the styling of the Header Row....